# When was I born?

Tags: knowledge, time

I was born just 10 minutes apart from my twin brother, but I celebrated my birthday 11 days after my twin brother every year.

When was I born ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You and your twin were born:

> 4th October 1582 and 15th October 1582, either side of the introduction of the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption).

Comment: They must be *old*.

Comment: I'll admit I often have problems counting, but is this not 11 days rather than 10?

Comment: @Mithrandir If you want them to be potentially still alive, they could be 14 days apart and born in Greece on Feb 14 and March 1 1923, respectively.

Comment: I had been thinking of Russia but the countries that switched in the 20th century had to drop 13 days (as the difference between the two calendars increases by roughly a day for each successive century).

Answer (score 1):

Your twin was born

> at 11.55 pm on 2 Sep 1752

and you were born

> at 12.05am on 14 Sep 1752 in England,when the Gregorian calendar was introduced there.

Just ten minutes apart,but 11 days and 10 minutes later you actually celebrate